# Why does order of declaration matter for annotated global variables in modules?

Tags: python

I am trying to import `main` from a module I'll call `tmp_test` with `import tmp_test.main`.

`main.py`   looks like this:

```py
def func():
    global x
x:int = 1
```

Running this code in an interactive shell is no problem, however when I try to import it, or run it from the command line using `python main.py`, I get:

```
SyntaxError: annotated name 'x' can't be global
```

Why is this?

Swapping the order of the statements to:

```py
x:int = 1
def func():
    global x
```

works fine.

Not including the annotation `:int`

```py
def func():
    global x
x = 1
```

also works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug of Python...

https://bugs.python.org/issue34939

so don't try too much to think to a logic reasoning behind this choice; it wasn't a choice but just happened. It's now fixed.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9844, it looks like this was fixed in a later version, thanks! For reference, I'm using python 3.7.3.